# Team Manager ID from resourceType and Department

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get ExternalID TeamManager2 for all resources by department in my query.
I don't think it's impossible to do but I get stuck.
Thanks in advance

**The query :**

```
SELECT
    T3.DeptGenius,
    T1.ResourceType,
    T1.ExternalID,
    T1.OfficeLocation,
    '' as 'ExternalIDTeamManager2'
FROM
    GEN_Resources T1
    INNER JOIN Ref_Resources T2 ON T1.ExternalID = T2.Unic_ID
    INNER JOIN Ref_BU T3 ON T2.BU_Unid = T3.UNID
WHERE
    T1.Active = 'YES'
```

**Actual result with the query :**

[image]

**Expected results :**

[image]
The logic is that there is only one Manager2 per department (deptGenius).

The list of departments is :
SOU, HR, FICO, CMU

An ExternalID is necessarily part of a department and has a resourceType.

If its ResourceType is different from Manager2, I would like the ExternalID column of Team Manager 2 to show the value of the ExternalID of Manager2 of its DeptGenius.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: how do you find  the manager2 ids? whats the relationship? fior example how do you find team manager 2 id for externalid FR0000023?

Comment: For exemple, FR0000023 is in CMU Department. The rule is: If ResourceType is different from 'Manager 2%' then retrieve the ExternalID for Department 'CMU' and ResourceType 'Manager2%'

Comment: I imagine it like that but I'm not sure it's the right way

Comment: The logic is that there is only one Manager2 per department (deptGenius). The list of departments is : 
SOU, HR, FICO, CMU
An ExternalID is necessarily part of a department and has a resourceType.
If its ResourceType is different from Manager2, I would like the ExternalID column of Team Manager 2 to show the value of the ExternalID of Manager2 of its DeptGenius.

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, here is what you need :

```
SELECT
    T3.DeptGenius,
    T1.ResourceType,
    T1.ExternalID,
    T1.OfficeLocation,
    m2.ExternalID as 'ExternalIDTeamManager2'
FROM
    GEN_Resources T1
INNER JOIN Ref_Resources T2 ON T1.ExternalID = T2.Unic_ID
INNER JOIN Ref_BU T3 ON T2.BU_Unid = T3.UNID
LEFT JOIN FEN_Resources m2 
    ON m2.resourcetype like 'Manager 2%'
    AND T1.resourcetype not like 'Manager 2%'
INNER JOIN Ref_Resources m2_2 ON m2.ExternalID = m2_2.Unic_ID
INNER JOIN Ref_BU m2_3 
    ON m2_2.BU_Unid = m2_3.UNID
    AND T3.DeptGenius = m2_3.DeptGenius
WHERE
    T1.Active = 'YES'
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you, it works. I just added m2.Active = 'Yes' in the Where.
I apologise for the poor quality of my explanations but thank you for helping me.

Comment: You are welcome , please accept/ upvote the answer if it helped